# Unity: What's allocating memory in my function?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, unity-game-engine, memory

I am relatively new to memory and optimization. I was tasked to optimize an existing project and while looking at the profiler in Unity, I saw that there was a function producing a bunch of stuff for the GC to clean up.

The function is as such:

```
public bool AnyCanvasOpen()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < canvasList.Count; i++)
        if (canvasList[i].activeSelf && canvasList[i].name != "MainUICanvas")
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

where canvasList is just a list of GameObjects. What could be the cause of my 282B allocation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `canvasList` variable is a `List` of `GameObject` and Unity's `GameObject` derives from [`UnityEngine.Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html) which has the [`name`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-name.html) property you are using.

The memory allocation came from that: `canvasList[i].name != "MainUICanvas"`

This is because the [`Object.name`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-name.html) property needs to return a string from the native side and this means that a new string is created each time that property is accessed. This is why the [`GameObject.CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.CompareTag.html) function was added, to make it possible to compare Object name without allocation memory. The `GameObject.CompareTag` function will compare the object name on the native side without the need to create or return a new string on the C# side. This removes the memory allocation.

Unfortunately, most Unity code examples on their site and elsewhere uses `Object.name` instead of the `GameObject.CompareTag` function which causes more people to use the `Object.name` property more often.

This shouldn't allocate memory:

```
List<GameObject> canvasList = new List<GameObject>();

public bool AnyCanvasOpen()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < canvasList.Count; i++)
        if (canvasList[i].activeSelf && canvasList[i].CompareTag("MainUICanvas"))
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it gave me a 6kb allocation instead. It seems like `GameObject.CompareTag` calls `LogStringToConsole` which had some allocation in it

However, it seems like memory allocation _did_ come from `canvasList[i].name != "MainUICanvas"`. Even though the provided solution didn't work as intended, technically you did answer my question, so this will be the accepted answer.

Comment: I ended up creating a new `List<string>` to contain the list of canvas names so that i didn't have to call `canvasList[i].name` a couple times per frame. This reduced the allocation to 0B. A better way to do this would be much appreciated

Comment: Not sure what you're saying. `CompareTag` does **not** allocate memory and nothing else in that function could. It doesn't matter if  memory allocation has been reduced or not. It should not allocate at-all. Note that if the tag you are comparing does not exist, you might see memory allocation in the profiler since Unity will [throw an error](https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-unity/wiki/Use-CompareTag-instead-of-explicit-string-comparison) and that memory allocation is due to the error log.

Comment: If that's not the case then the memory allocation is from *another place*. Enable deep profile to find that. Finally, note that you should be debugging the built/standalone project not from the Editor project as there are some allocations that happens in the Editor but not in the build.

Comment: I wasn't saying that `GameObject.CompareTag` itself had some allocation, it was _something_ that came along with it that did(which was indeed an error) and my apologies if I phrased it in a way you didn't understand. The memory allocation was the error log as what I was trying to compare was `GameObject.name` and not the tag. Trying to use `GameObject.CompareTag` produced an error since the canvas I was trying to find was untagged. Thanks for the help